# How to remotely live debug node.js app, while running on Azure App Service on Linux

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to remotely debug a node.js app while it is running on Azure App Service on Linux. VSCode's [Azure Remote Debugging for Node.js](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/remote-debugging) is not working for me, so I'm trying [remote debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_remote-debugging) through a SSH session opened with Azure CLI's [create-remote-connection](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/05/07/New-SSH-Experience-and-Remote-Debugging-for-Linux-Web-Apps.html) command.

```
az webapp create-remote-connection –g [resource group] -n [app name] -p 9229
```

My launch.json file has

```
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to remote",
            "address": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 9229,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/home/site/wwwroot",

        }
```

Next, I run SSH on my machine with

```
ssh -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 root@127.0.0.1
```

but I don't know what to do next. How do I remotely live debug this app, while it is running on Azure App Service on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a remote connection to your app using the [az webapp remote-connection create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session#open-ssh-session-from-remote-shell) command.

```
az webapp create-remote-connection –g [resource group] -n [app name]
```

The command output gives you the information you need to open an SSH session.

```
Verifying if app is running....
App is running. Trying to establish tunnel connection...
Opening tunnel on port: 49288
SSH is available { username: root, password: Docker! }
```

Initiate a local SSH tunnel, using the port from the output above.

```
ssh -L  9221:127.0.0.1:9229 root@127.0.0.1 -p 49288
```

This starts a ssh tunnel session where a connection to port 9221 on your local machine will be forwarded to port 9229 on the remote container running in App Service.

Once authenticated, run the `top` command to get the pid of your node app. Let's say it's `67`. Run [`node inspect`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#enabling-remote-debugging-scenarios).

```
node inspect -p 67
```

Run VSCode with the configuration in launch.json

```
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to remote",
            "address": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 9221,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/home/site/wwwroot",

        },
```